# JavaScript file did not work in html when changing next.js to node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, next.js

I wrote a javascript before, and using the guide of next.js to run it(npm run dev)and it worked. Now I want to make it run in my html file using node.js(node app.js) but it seems not work.

in the html I used "" (index.js is my previous js which created when using next.js) And I have already put index.js into assets/js

Below is index.js

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
import styled from 'styled-components';

const TiltWrap = styled.div`
    perspective: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
`;
const TiltStyles = styled.div`
    background-image: url('images/drone.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
    transform: 
    rotateX(${30}deg)
    rotateY(${20}deg)
    rotate(${50}deg);
    position: relative;
`;

const Index = ({pitch, roll, yaw}) => (
    <TiltWrap>
        Pitch: {pitch}
        Roll: {roll}
        Yaw: {yaw}
        <TiltStyles pitch={pitch} roll={roll} yaw={yaw} />
    </TiltWrap>
);

Index.defaultProps = {
    pitch: 0,
    roll: 0,
    yaw: 0,
};

export default Index;

//for the html, I used below
<script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
```

I want it run in my html but after I added it, nothing happened on my website(also didn't work in DreamWeaver)
Should I modify other files? Like package-lock.jason? app.js?

Comment: For me, your explanation is very unclear. Can you post working, minimal example that will show us an error?

Comment: I added the code below which is I added in the html, there is no error but I can't see any difference on my website after I quoted the index.js.

Comment: "Now I want to make it run in my html file using node.js" ... What do you mean? NodeJS is a server side framework, it does not run in the browser